# How to overload cout behaviour in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout

I would like to make cout will always print additional string (above and under) whenever I call it. It is weird to me because I use in Java and C# primarily.

### Edit

Maybe we can define other value for "y" string or something like that?

### Example

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){std::cout<<"y\n";}
```

result(printed):

```
x
y
z
```

I would not want to change `int main()` method just maybe overriding the `<<` for the string type?

Or maybe make cout invoke additional method?

Comment: You cannot overload `operator<<` for the standard types.

Comment: @meh maybe overloading string operator would help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with cout. What you can do instead is create a simple I/O wrapper that does your extra printing and then calls into cout to do the real work.

Comment: or replace couts streambuf to do this

Comment: @PlasmaHH it couldn't tell where the end of the call to the `operator<<`s were.

Comment: Also to the OP, you'll need to make use of move semantics and destructors to do this at the end of a string of `<<` operations instead of after every one.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: neither could a simple replacement for cout, you would need to overload all op<< too.

Comment: Mark B how to do it. Without changing int method.

Comment: @PlasmaHH nope, you can do it once with templates. (Actually you need two, one more for function pointers).

Comment: I know what you meant now but it does not cut the mustard. I would like to make cout invokes maybe other method which prints x and z or whatever else, maybe not elegant, maybe define other value for that "x" string.