# How to overload << for string in c++

Tags: c++, string, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overload cout behaviour in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649920/how-to-overload-cout-behaviour-in-c)

I would like to make cout act different for string. for example it will always add "Hello" before handovered string. So this is basically overloading operator but for String. How to do it?

Example

```
std::cout<<" Kermit";
```

Result

```
Hello Kermit
```

Comment: For a string LITERAL? Please...just no....

Answer (score 2):

Please don't:

```
struct X
{
   X& operator << (const char* x)
   {
      std::cout << "Hello " << x;
      return *this;
   }
};

//...
X cout;
cout << "Kermit";
```

Comment: that's just plain evil... :D

Comment: I have made an edit which should be done before, sorry.
std::cout<<"Kermit"; this std complicates it

Comment: What about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515925/c-string-operator-overload THE answer, but actually don't know how to use it cause it seems not to work.

Comment: @user1825608 nope, you can't directly overload the operator for built-in types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper around your literals...

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
  foo(const char* s) : str(s) {}

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, foo const& f)
  { return s << "Hello " << f.str; }

  const char* str;
};

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << foo("Kermit") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to leave 
std::cout <<"Kermit" << std::endl;

Comment: @user1825608, erm, no. Well, not easily.. actually, plain no is possibly going to save you a lot time bothering...

Comment: I have found sotheming like that(look at the answer) but do not know how to actually use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515925/c-string-operator-overload the truth is this is friend of mine task and I offerred help but c++ is evil to me.